# Can't choose "More" when choosing application language in Edit Scheme

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I'm trying to account for both English and Georgian and an app I'm developing. I had added the localization language to the project, have all the storyboard languages setup and the strings files.

I now want to test to see if the text translates correctly.

However, when I go to Edit Scheme and find the application language drop down it doesn't have Georgian.

When I added the localization in the project settings I could go to a More menu that had LOADS of languages. Why does this not exist in the Application Language drop down in the scheme settings?

[image]

EDIT:

Tried the solution below by adding language and locale as arguments:

[image]

I have what I believe is the correct setup for translating strings depending on the language of the phone etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xcode scheme Debug options only include a subset of languages plus pseudolanguages for testing. However, there are workarounds.

If you want to see if text translates correctly, do one of the following:

1. Go to your scheme's Arguments tab and add the `AppleLanguages` and `AppleLocale` to the "Arguments Passed On Launch" section.

   For example, to select the Georgian language and the Georgian region, you'd   add:

```
  -AppleLanguages "(ka-GE)"
  -AppleLocale "GEO"
```

or:

2. On the device or simulator, set the region and language in the device's Preferences and then run your app.

More here: [Internationalization and Localization Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/TestingYourInternationalApp/TestingYourInternationalApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH7-SW1)

Note that the ISO language code for Georgia is "ka-GE", not "ge". You should have "ka-GE.lproj" as your localization folder name.

The language code comes from the ISO codes here: [ISO 639-2 codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes), and the region code comes from these: [ISO_3166-2 codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2)

One other thing I just noticed is that your string translation files are called "Localize.strings". The default filename is "Localizable.strings" and if you're calling `NSLocalizedString` without providing an explicit file name in the optional `table` parameter, that's what iOS looks for. So, you'll probably need to rename your translation files for things to work.

Comment: I have tried adding this using 'ge' as the Language and en_US as the locale. i'll add an image to the OP. I run the app in debug mode on my device and get this error: 2019-04-18 09:37:31.736339-0700 gnccapp[19899:5425316] [strings] ERROR: Start Test not found in table Localizable of bundle CFBundle 0x105400590 </var/containers/Bundle/Application/1B229236-2F20-4E28-BBA7-7A13F6B74CB0/gnccapp.app> (executable, loaded). I have set up ge and english as language files with the strings I want in them

Comment: Error has gone, I had a setting enabled when it shouldn't have been. However, I'm still not able to get the language to work using the scheme edit shown in my OP. I also can't set my phone to use Georgian!! I can change my Region to Georgia. I can add the Georgian language to my language but setting my iPhone language to Georgian does not exist! So frustrating

Comment: I've updated the answer based on my working tests here. Also, I found that if you set the *language* on the phone/simulator before changing the *region*, you can set Georgia(n) for both.

Comment: Thanks! Is the hypen in front of the Apple for the arguments needed? I'm not using a hyphen and don't have any luck. Also, where should I look for the ka.lproj folder? All I did was create a string file and add the Georgian localization

Comment: I've found it. The folder name is ka-GE. This is what xCode created when I Added the language

Comment: yeah was just noticing that. if you make it with Xcode's menus, it names it that. And yes, you should include the "-" before the launch arguments. I updated the arguments in the answer to reflect what you should set.

Comment: I have that now but still no luck. I'll post another question about how to actually code for localization as I must have done something wrong on that front. I'll post a link here when I'm done if you'd be so kind as to review that, too.

Comment: just added one more hint at the bottom of the answer. hopefully that gets it working.

Comment: You sir are my hero. JOB DONE. Thank you!